# Nonnegativity of solutions of first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I had a one-dimensional first order differential equation

$$y'(t)=f(y,t), y(0)>0$$

where I'm only interested in $t>0$. Now if I knew that $f(0,t)>0$ this would suggest that the solution curves $y(t)$ are always non-negative. What if $f(0,t)=0$? Would this be enough? If not, does anyone have any examples of an equation where $f(0,t)=0$ and it's obvious that the solution curves become negative at some point?